# Sacar dias de diferencia

Tags: mysql, sql

En la siguiente consulta la columna '**ROUPMJ**' la uso como fecha para saber cuando está disponible un producto, pero al venir en *Juliana* lo he convertido a `smalldatetime`.

Necesito sacar la diferencia de días al día actual en otra columna tomando como fecha inicio el campo '**ROUPMJ**'. Esto con la finalidad de saber cuántos días pasan a partir de que el producto está disponible.

Adjunto el código:

```
With CT_Recibo AS 
( 
    SELECT
        CASE WHEN ROPOST = 5 THEN 'Liberado' END AS Estatus,  
        DateAdd (d,cast(ROUPMJ as int) - ((cast(ROUPMJ as int) / 1000) * 1000),
        convert(smalldatetime,str((cast(ROUPMJ as int) / 1000) + 1900) + '0101')) - 1 AS Fecha,
        ROTDAY 'Hora Liberacion',
        ROEDOC 'Documento Ingreso',
        ROVINV'Factura',
        RODOCO 'No Orden',
        RODCTO 'Tipo Documento',
        ROLNID 'Linea',
        ROSFXO 'No De Recibo',
        ROLITM 'Codigo',
        RODSC1'Descripcion Codigo',
        ROUORG'Cantidad Solicitada',
        ROUREC'Cantidad Recibida',
        ROPOST
    FROM f55m4324 
    WHERE ROPOST IN ('5') 
        AND ROEDOC NOT IN (SELECT ROEDOC FROM F55M4324 WHERE ROPOST IN ('7'))
) SELECT* FROM CT_Recibo
```

Comment: Por favor **[edit] la pregunta** agregando información de ejemplo de las tablas involucradas en esta consulta y agrega cuáles son los resultados esperados.